# Javascript/jQuery hash URL doesn't execute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a `hash URL` that doesn't execute the `javascript/jQuery` unless I manually hit the enter key or refresh the page.

```
$(function($){
  var key=$(location).attr('hash');

  if (key){
    $('#div').find('div.div2').load('sig.php?k='+key)
  }
});
```

This works fine when I type in the `URL` manually or refresh the page but whenever I use `<a href="url#SecReTkEy">` or `Javascript/jQuery` functions such as:

`$(location).attr('href','url#SecReTkEy');`

`$('a').prop('href','url#SecReTkEy');`

`window.location.replace('url#SecReTkEy');`

`window.location.href('url#SecReTkEy');`

Can any one tell me why and how to fix this?
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`I have a hash URL that doesn't execute the javascript/jQuery unless I manually hit the enter key or refresh the page.`

This was due to it only launching once rather than having an `eventBinder` on `hashchange`.

Answer (score 0):

you should use

```
location.href = #whatever
```

Comment: location.hash, surely?

Comment: @garryp @RDeving `location.hash` doesn't work either.

Comment: You must be doing something wrong. location.hash is supported by all major browsers http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_loc_hash.asp

Answer (score 0):

You don't need JQuery in order to retrieve the hash. Use the fully qualified reference to `window.location.hash` (I'm guessing `location` didn't work as you already have a var named `location`).

Also, don't forget to URL encode the key using `encodeURIComponent`. Additionally the `$` is not needed [if you want to execute this on document ready](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/).

```
$(function(){
  var key = window.location.hash;

  if (key){
    $('#div').find('div.div2').load('sig.php?k=' + encodeURIComponent(key))
  }
});
```